# Apache CGI-Bin Hot Update

Tags: apache-2.4

We use Apache to host our website which we update a couple of times a day. Currently we update by having a list of `.exe`'s that apache looks through, and we update them in turn. The fundamental limitation to this that is that we can only update a fixed number of times a day. I know hot-updates are a thing that can be done, but I'm not entirely sure where how to do this or even where to look for resources.

On to the question:

Is there a configuration I can do that can tell Apache to hot-update an `.exe`? Or is there a tool that allows for it?

Comment: Eh? Is your application an .exe then? On Windows? Why not use FPM?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm part of a team, so I don't have as much control, and I haven't heard of FPM. Looking it up now.

Comment: See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html for the apache end of the setup. Your application, of course, will need to be modified to support FastCGI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have updates to different files to become effective at the same time, you can upload them to a new directory, and then change an `Alias` or `ScriptAlias` to the new directory.

Comment: Is this something I can change while apache is running? As far as I can tell it isn't.

Comment: You can reload the Apache configuration while Apache is running. You can also use symlinks, they work also on Windows.